# Dual Boot Windows 10 with elementary OS

Tags: release-freya, dual-boot, microsoft-windows

I have elementary OS (Freya) installed on my system, as the only OS, but now I will like to also install Windows 10 and make the system dual boot, I do not want to loose my files or settings on the elementary OS. I have searched online on how to do this, but most of the tutorials goes from Windows to elementary OS, what I want is the other way round.

Comment: Note: Installing Windows 10 destroyed my other partitions, and just left them blank. Backup first.

Answer (score 2):

Read this post here:

[install windows after installing ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu)

This post has good explained answers on how to solve your problem. These answers will also work for elementary as both uses GRUB.